# Getting extras from an intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, extras

I have an issue that is driving me crazy, I want to get "n" string values from a bundle, somehow avd crashes when I click on "send button".

Activity 1

```
public void enviar(View view){
    Intent intento=new Intent(this, Segunda.class);

    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    String usuarioS=editText.getText().toString();
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuarioID);        
    bundle.putString("usuario", usuarioS);
    intento.putExtras(bundle);



    startActivity(intento);
}
```

Activity 2

```
public class Segunda extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);      


    String message,message1;

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            message1 = extras.getString("usuario"); 
            TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usuariofID);       
            textView1.setText(message1);



}
```

That's my code. Where am I messing up?

**LOGCAT(update)**

```
01-22 19:54:54.055: W/Trace(1270): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-22 19:54:54.104: D/AndroidRuntime(1270): Shutting down VM
01-22 19:54:54.104: W/dalvikvm(1270): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     ... 11 more
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):atcom.example.actividadesss.MainActivity.enviar(MainActivity.java:301-22 19:54:54.155: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):   ... 14 more
01-22 19:54:54.224:W/ActivityManager(286):Forcefinishingactivitycom.example.actividadesss/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: Why do you have `editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuarioID);`? Do you want to read the String from `editText` or `editText1`? And you are using the same id in different layouts, is this intentional?

Comment: is editText initialized?

Comment: if look closely, there are to different ID´s, first one belongs to an editext where i put some string value, second one belongs to a textView where i show the string i wrote before

Comment: Also, a good habit is to name the variables, classes and methods in English. Just a thought.

Comment: i just update the post and put logcat :)

Answer (score 1):

it seems as though you are using the EditText field prior to establishing it. can you try...

**from:**

```
public void enviar(View view){
   ...
   String usuarioS=editText.getText().toString();
   editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuarioID);
   ...
}
```

**to:**

```
public void enviar(View view){
   ...
   editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuarioID);
   String usuarioS=editText.getText().toString();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would suggest getting rid of the code that isn't needed. You can use Intent.putExtra() rather than making a bundle and putting the bundle in the Intent. Minimizing code can help debug your problem and sometimes even solve it.

And I agree with David M on initializing your EditText before using it.

```
public void enviar(View view){
    Intent intento=new Intent(this, Segunda.class);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuarioID);
    String usuarioS=editText.getText().toString();
    intento.putExtra("usuario", usuarios);

    startActivity(intento);
}
```

[Understanding Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)